# Dropping search results by score in Solr

Tags: php, apache, search, solr, lucene

I found that you could get the score  related to a search in Solr by setting the "fl" parameter as "fl=score". Lets say that I need to filter this further by only getting the ads that have a mean score.

Like
`mean_score = ( score_1 + score_2 + score_3 ... + score_n )` .

Drop ads that are `ad_score < mean_score`

Is it possible to do it through Solr, dropping results by score?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry about that, will edit the post..

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Solr supports aggregations like that in function queries, so this would have to be done as post-processing on the result set.

However, this is really not a good idea.  Lucene scoring is not intended to work in this way.

For one thing, differences in score often have a tendency to be large.  The difference between a best result and a close result could be a whole order of magnitude, rather than, say, a 10% drop.  Trying to assign an arbitrary cutoff point that works in all cases is not really feasible.  Running some [explain queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debug.explain.structured) might give you a view of this sort of thing.

Further, your cutoff point will may have a tendency to move.  If new documents are added, documents contents are changed, etc., the scores for documents can change, even if the documents the search found remained unchanged.  This can lead to a search finding the desired document one day, and the being unable to the next for no readily discernable reason, which could be quite frustrating.

See the article: [Scores As Percentages](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages) for more on this.

The better approach would be to structure queries in such a way as to embed a cutoff within them.  `edixmax` has a number of tools to use for this.  Among others, the [`mm` (Min Should Match)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) parameter may be helpful.